# How to get index from selectedvalue of a checkedlistbox control?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkedlistbox

Among other controls in a windows form, i have a CheckedListBox containing numerous items.The code for populating the CheckedListBox is:

```
Dictionary<string, string> ciDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
ciDict.Add("1", "Audi");
ciDict.Add("2", "Suzuki");
ciDict.Add("3", "Saab");
ciDict.Add("4", "Tata");

clb.DataSource = new BindingSource(ciDict, null);
clb.DisplayMember = "Value";
clb.ValueMember = "Key";
```

When i save data in the table, i am saving the 'ValueMember'.Now in Edit mode of the said form, i want CheckedListBox items to be Checked using the valuemember saved earlier.My problem is how to find the index of CheckedListBox  items from its valuemember???Hope you understand my question.

```
while (rdrCCA.Read())
{
   int index= clbCSA.Items.IndexOf(rdrCCA["CCA_ITEM_ID"]);
   clbCSA.SetItemChecked(index, true);
}
```

where

```
clbCSA= name of the checkedlistbox control
CCA_ITEM_ID = name of the table field where valumember are being stored.
```

This code does not work.Please advice with some code.

Comment: Do you get an exception? What happens in the while loop?  Any chance the values in the dictionary and those coming from the DB get out of sync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is in a dictionary, the most simple way to find the index by value is finding index of the value in dictionary this way:

```
var index = yourDictionary.Keys.ToList().IndexOf("SomeValue");
if(index > -1)
    checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(index, true);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Reza, you helped me with your code once again.Last time about 1 years ago you had helped me with my code.

Comment: The call to `.Cast<string>()` is unnecessary since the value of the `.Keys` property will implement `IEnumerable<string>`.  Also, it's not quite as terse but you can avoid the list creation with `var searchIndex = ciDict.Select((pair, index) => new { pair.Key, Index = index }).Single(item => item.Key == "SomeValue").Index;` (or substitute `.First()` for `.Single()` since we know there can't be duplicate keys).

Comment: @BACON, I think that should be: ciDict.Select((kv, Index) => new {kv, Index}).Where(o => o.kv.Value == "Saab").First().Index;  What you had didn't work for me, especially since the value is a string, not the key.

Comment: @Loring I prefer the `Keys.ToList()`  which is more readable for future readers :)

Comment: @Loring Your code and mine are mostly the same, except I retrieve the needed property of the `KeyValuePair<>` in `.Select()` whereas you do it in your predicate, and I use the overload of `.Single()`/`.First()` that accepts a predicate to eliminate the call to `.Where()`.  I had it filter by `.Key` and not `.Value` simply because that's equivalent to the code in this answer.  Now that you mention it, it does seem like keys/value got reversed in this answer and/or the original dictionary in the question, but the answer was accepted so evidently the gist of the code was understood.

Comment: @BACON Both key and value are string in the question `Dictionary<string, string> ciDict` and the OP is looking for key, as they said: *When I save data in the table, I am saving the 'ValueMember'.* and they set `clb.ValueMember = "Key"`. I Also believe it's better to define key as `int`, but probably the OP knows the difference :)